# Complexidade assintótica de função

Tags: funções, algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Quando eu tenho uma função de duas variáveis como:

```
f(x, y) = log y + 3 * x^4
```

Posso dizer que o domínio assintótica da função é `theta(x^4)`? Ou eu tenho que considerar as duas variáveis e definir como `Omega(y + x)`?

Comment: As duas variáveis precisam constar na classificação, independente se a complexidade assintótica está sendo limitada por Omega, Theta ou Omicron.

Answer (score 1):

É apenas x^4 porque ela claramente domina para valores grandes de x.

Comment: Independente de quem domina, são duas variáveis e as duas precisam constar.